# why is "org-highlight-latex-and-related" messing with org-hyperlink description?

Tags: org-mode, latex, syntax-highlighting

Basically, to highlight latex equation I need to include `native` in `org-highlight-latex-and-related`.

But that messes up links with `_` (`[[file:asdfk_jkfke_erj224jk.txt][a link]]` for the example below).

(Perhaps emacs mistakes the links as a latex related stuff.)

**Question**:

- how to highlight equations without messing with links?
- Is this a bug? or Am I doing something wrong.

[image]

To reproduce you can use following org file.
The image above is the screen of `emacs -Q` of file below (my version is 29.1)

```org
* Latex equations, and links  
\begin{equation}
    A := \int \frac{1}{x ( \log x ) ^2} dx
\end{equation}


[[file:asdfk_jkfke_erj224jk.txt][a link]]

\[
\alpha+ \beta
\]

* Hightlight Configuration
** without ~native~
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results none
(setq org-highlight-latex-and-related     '(latex script entities ))
(org-mode-restart)
#+end_src


** with ~native~ conflicts link
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results none
(setq org-highlight-latex-and-related     '(latex script entities native))
(org-mode-restart)
#+end_src
```